# How can I get a UTC Time in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, utc

How can I get the current UTC time in JavaScript, but not from user's clock?

If I use Date() Object, the system returns the user's time from his clock and, for the user, is easy to change it.

Comment: Retrieve it from a trusted server.

Comment: Either find a server which provides some API like that, or configure your own server to do so.

Comment: Everything you've written I could have written myself. If you do not have an answer to my question please do not write more.

Answer (score 0):

We can get UTC time indirectly from the Current Date , time and timezone offset .

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

The time-zone offset is the difference, in minutes, between UTC and local time. Note that this means that the offset is positive if the local timezone is behind UTC and negative if it is ahead .

Using this one to compute the current UTC time.

Comment: This gets the user's time, but his clock might be misconfigured.

Comment: Yes , this is with the assumption the clock is in sync with the time server even in the case of misconfigured time zone.

Comment: The user can change his timezone (like his time and date) so this function is not correct.